# gkSudo Error no matter what I do

Tags: debian, gnome, sudo

I don't know why, It wasn't happening yesterday. Was it because I turned the machine off and back on again this morning?

Anyway here's the error. GkSudo won't run anything at all now.

> (gksudo:3262): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_str_has_prefix: assertion `str != NULL' failed

This happens no matter what. Funny thing is, gkSudo comes up with the password box, I enter the root password, then the problem happens.

I want my gksudo back  can anyone help? I cannot find documentation for this error at all. I don't know where to look, this is my second ever day using Linux.

I'm on Debian Gnome.

Comment: Are you sure you should enter the `root` password? Normally sudo asks you to enter your own password. Also, it might help if you specify the exact version of Debian you are on (see /etc/debian_version if you are uncertain) and any changes (package updates, configuration changes, etc.) that you have done recently.

Comment: Is `sudo` working?

Comment: This is the same question as [this problem in ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217976/gksudo-fails-with-critical-error), and it's not a problem with sudo, the password entered, or anything else, it's a bug, reported both in [ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgksu/+bug/501559) and [debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=686844).